# Can I directly store a type in an ADOJobStore in Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz.net

I would like to execute a job that requires that I save a type in the JobDataMap. This will later be used along with the ID of an entity to rehydrate the entity so the job can use it.

I know I could get the AssemblyQualifiedName of the type and store that, then use GetType() in the job, but before I go down that path, I thought I'd see if quartz just does this for me.

If I put a type in the JobDataMap, will it serialize and deserialize when I access the property later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it will. You can use the JobDataMap indexer to store arbitrary data. Type instances are quite safe, but you need to be extra careful about versions (using only assembly qualified name removes this problem), namespaces and public keys.

If there were a slight possibility that the type might change after persisting I would recommended using a 'meta name' like 'BackupJobHelperType' that you would then resolve to the actual type. Generelly always prefer simple serialization safe types over own types, if possible set *quartz.jobStore.useProperties* to true which will enforce string key and values.

You can save the info when building the job and it will be available when the job starts.

Comment: The object has to be serializable in the first place.  I don't think you can put a IDataReader (SqlDataReader) in the "Map".